# Append extracted column to list without index: Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I have the dataframe as follows:

| Name | Year | Class |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Roy | 2001 | 12 |
| Pete | 2001 | 12 |

I am executing some function where I need one segment of code to get class of particular student and append to list.
I used the following.

```
EmpList = []
c1 = d1["Class"].loc[Emp["Name"]=="Roy"]
EmpList.append(c1)
```

Before appending class column, I have already succesfully appended marks of student from another dataframe.
But when I append the class column and print the list, the index of the Class column also gets printed. After converting list to Dataframe I get As follows:

| Name | marks1 | marks2 | Class |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Roy | 23 | 24 | 0 12 |

and so on...
The problem is only with class column.
Kindly suggest
Not only, index. But it is also storing Name: Class, dtype:object in the list.
Shall I convert series to any other datatype? Or is there any other way to append it?

Comment: Because `c1` is a `Series` not a scalar value. `type(c1)` should output `pandas.core.series.Series`

Comment: Yes. The type command shows it is Series. So how can I append it? I m just 2 days old to learning python pandas. kindly give me lead.

Comment: I used series.tostring() function but still index is there.

Comment: series.tolist() is working but getting square brackets.

Comment: `series.tolist()[0]` to extract the first element? If you are sure 'Roy' appears only once in your dataframe `Emp`

Comment: Yes! it worked. Thank you soo much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure to have only one instance of 'Roy' in your dataframe, you can use `squeeze`:

```
EmpList = []
c1 = d1["Class"].loc[Emp["Name"]=="Roy"].squeeze()  # <- HERE
EmpList.append(c1)
```